# Is a phrase ending ; viio --> I ( both chords in Root position ) considered an Authentic cadence?

Tags: theory, chords

In a baroque binary minuet by J.C.F. Fischer , starting in F major , the first phrase ends with E dim ( E-G-B flat ) viio --> I (F-A-C ) . The soprano notes move from B flat to A. Can this cadence in F major be named as AC or IAC ( Authentic Cadence or Imperfect Authentic Cadence) ?

Comment: May I ask which one? I only ask because, in my experience, it's *exceedingly* rare for a vii° triad to be in root position, and I'd love to have the example marked for future reference.

Comment: @Richard - This binary minuet ( 8m + 16m = 24measure ) is found in Level 9 Harmony , 2018 Edition - Official Examination Papers - The Royal Conservatory of Music -pages 44 & 45 , Published by RCM Publishing , an imprint of The Frederick Harris Music Co.Ltd; 273 Bloor St West , Toronto , Ontario , M5S 1W2 , 1-800-387-4013 . www.rcmpublishing.com ( I will be writing this exam this May 2020 )

Comment: Would you post a screen shot?

Comment: @Richard, is root position `viio` found when the tonic is minor? I seem to recall there is a difference depending on major/minor tonic.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS sorry , my current available devices are not able to post a screen shot. You can order the exam book containing 4 L9 Harmony exams from RCM (where I am a student )

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Yes the root position viio is found in Harmonic minor keys and in major keys.When the leading note is raised in minor keys you can get viio.

Comment: Hey @Richard how do you get the superscript "o" for your diminished vii ?

Comment: @Thomas Copy and paste :-)

Comment: @Richard vii° triad = it works , Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an imperfect authentic cadence because 5-1 is not the bass.

See https://music.utk.edu/theorycomp/courses/murphy/documents/cadences.pdf

Comment: Imperfect Authentic Cadence ( IAC ) because 5-1 is not the bass. Marvelous Donald Hosek ! Great summary sheet on cadences too.